# Tense use in the Rolling Stones song "As tears go by"

Tags: present-tense, lyrics

Is the use of the Present Simple grammatically accurate in these lyrics, or is it an example of so-called poetic license that allows for violating grammar rules for the sake of rhyme:

> It is the evening of the day
>   I sit and watch the children play
>   Smiling faces I can see, but not for me
>   I sit and watch as tears go by

If we read the lyrics as a prose text, wouldn't the Present Continuous be a more correct choice here since the text describes an ongoing process at the particular moment? The whole scene can also be seen as a picture requiring the Present Continuous for its description too.

Comment: Pop song lyrics are usually written after the tune, and they are required to fit that.  Grammar is not a consideration.

Comment: The Rolling Stones have said in interviews that they pick the vowels for their songs before the pick the actual words. ([Keith Richards calls it “vowel movement”](https://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=136497217)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple present is correct. This is an example of "commentary", the speaker is describing something as it happens, which is a use for the simple present. It is rather rare, as we don't normally describe things as they happen.

It would also be possible to use a present continuous, and in prose that tense would be more common.

Comment: Thanks! Are the present simple and present continuous interchangeable, when commenting? The present continuous is used in "Tom's Diner" by Suzanne Vega.

Comment: I would call it a "narrative present".

Comment: Do you see any difference between the simple and continuous forms in regard to commenting?

Comment: Also the "narrative present" is sometimes used in children's stories, *"Benny the Badger **looks** out from his hole.  "What a lovely morning it **is**!" he **thinks**."*

Comment: @AlexeyPlatonov  Note that "Tom's Diner" uses a mix of both present simple and present continuous.  I think Suzanne Vega picked the continuous tense because the "-ing" form of verbs all have a similar accent which matches the rhythm she wanted for the song.  Semantically both the present simple and the present continuous suggest the narrator is a *detached observer*, but this might also be the effect of the actual context.

Comment: @Andrew, Thank you! It's still not clear to me if there is any difference in meaning between the continuous and the simple form in narrative. What shall I consider when choosing between them?